# Twilio Say vs Play verb performance

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Hi I was curious about the performance between the `<Play>` and `<Say>` twiml verbs.

I have noticed that the same set of texts when generated on the fly using the `<Say>` verb is actually between .2-.4 seconds quicker than using the `<Play>` to send a prerecorded audio file.

I am modifying an inprogress call using the [twilio node wrapper](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress-node-js) to deliver the audio.

My question is, how come generating audio on the fly using the `<Say>` verb is faster than just playing an audio file using `<Play>`. I ran it a few times so twilio would cache the audio files, but it `<Play>` was still slower. I read about Twilio caching [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/play#hints)

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [request inspector](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136407-Debugging-your-application), viewable when clicking a call in the call logs, to see the file request time, to verify the file indeed has been cached. There are quite a number of servers involved, so it may take time for your media files to be cached (if the cache headers are set correctly).

The closer you can locate your media files to us-east-1 (AWS Region), the lower the request latency. You can host the media file on [Twilio Assets](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019105433-Getting-Started-with-Twilio-Assets) or an AWS S3 bucket and compare the times to your own servers hosting the media files.

Also verify the [format of the media file](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180588-Best-Practices-for-Audio-Recordings#:%7E:text=Record%20your%20source%20at%2044.1,get%20very%20best%20audio%20quality.&text=After%20recording%2C%20archive%20your%20recordings%20in%20that%20source%20format.), to minimize transcoding when possible.

Comment: Hi @Alan thank you I will check this out. Assuming that the files are cached and the media file format is optimized, will the ```<Play>``` verb be faster?

Comment: I've not tested personally but cached file access is often around 10ms-20ms last I checked.

Comment: in the documentation I read this "Twilio will attempt to cache the audio file the first time it is played." However I have run my conversation with the same audio files about 10 times and the files are not being cached. I checked that the ETag and Last-Modified headers were set correctly (I am using expressJS). Any ideas?